# Missing Connection String in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an EF4 domain project that houses the model and context which has an app.config that has a connectionStrings section.

I also have a MVC project that references the domain project. This MVC project has a web.config into which i have pasted the connectionStrings section from the domain app.config.

I then in the global.ascx.cs inside the application_start method iterate through the connection string using the following, but i never seen the connection string that i have pasted into the web config. The only connection string is "LocalSqlServer" that i cannot find anywhere.

```
ConnectionStringSettingsCollection connections = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
foreach ( ConnectionStringSettings connection in connections )
{
    string connectionString = connection.ConnectionString;
}
```

I believe that since this connection string named "OrganiserEntities" is not being found it is causing the following error:
"The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid."

Can anyone help?
This is causing the following

Comment: Can you provide your web.config for us to see? Be sure that you are editing the web.config at your project's root, and not the one in the Views folder

Comment: Nikmd23: You were right I was editing the wrong the web.config. It was placing the connection string information in the View folders web.config. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving ConnectionStrings from app.config to web.config. Or use `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(filePath)` to open your app.config file

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, connection strings are usually stored in the web.config in the root of your MVC project, not the views/web.config